# SQL Query to get count of the result

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, syntax-error

I have been able to execute a complex query that executed well, however, I am struggling to get the count of the result.

I have tried `select count (*) as TotalCount(*Complete query inside*)` but is showing syntax error 3707.

Comment: please show your sql or simpler version sql

Comment: I have some comments (comments inside)

Answer (score 1):

You can use your original query in the `from` clause:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (SELECT something
        FROM   somewhere
        WHERE  some_condition = 'some_value, etc.') t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your complex query as sub query and write as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (your complex query);
```

This will work as you complex query will result into a resultset, which will act as a table for count query.

Comment: Subqueries used with from or joins require an alias (`t` in the other answer)